# twitter Bootstrap: my thumbnails pop out in a column when reducing the size of screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design, modal-dialog, thumbnails

I have a problem using thumbnails class in my design. I want a row of 5 pictures stay as a row while reducing the size of window so the user uses modal window to see larger photos, but as soon as the size of the window reduces photos jump out in one column. how can I solve it?
I have used this setup in my HTML to put the thumbnails as you can see in the following link:
here 
[the link](http://www.northeastern.edu/sds/web/demos/demos_climate_prec_001.shtml)

Click "ncar_ccsm3_0" on top left of "CMIP3 models" to see the thumbnails. in full size monitor they are lined in a row and pushing each one opens a modal window to show the large size.

It is great. but as soon as I make the window smaller thumbnails pop out in a column, which I do not want to happen. how can I manage it so in every size the thumbnails stay in a row?
the structure is:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="span12">
    <ul class="thumbnails">
      <li class="span2">
        <a href="link to upper photo"
        <a href="link to down photo"
      ...
      ...repeated for 5 columns
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I don't see the problem you are describing. The site seems to work for me. When I view the thumbnails and shrink the window they stay organized the same way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
.table th, .table td {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. yes. I added them all in a 2 row table.